How to get list of keywords in a module / test file robotframework
I have a robot test file that looks like
*** Test Cases ***
My Test
    @{works}=    Create List
    ...    Do Work 1
    ...    Do Work 2

    FOR    ${i}    IN    @{works}
        Run Keyword    ${i}
    END


*** Keywords ***
Do Work 1
    Log    Hello

Do Work 2
    Log    World

Not Work 5
    Fail

The @{works} list needs to contain all keywords in this test file that start with "Do Work". Currently I have to manually maintain it when a new keyword is added. Is there a way to automatically get all keyword names in robot framework? This way I can filter the keywords that start with "Do Work" and construct the @{works} list automatically.
If possible, I want to avoid getting list of keywords by reading and parsing the test file. I hope that I can get the list from some data structure in robotframework’s Python runtime.
